# Get data cache from Jsoup connect when offline

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem, when the device is online, i can read the news to my website, i parsing use library jsoup, but when the device is offline, the pages that were read will be empty,
My question is how when offline i can still read the news already read, whether it is stored in the cache, and if stored how do i get it?
My code below is the data from my website i put in the variable DATA.
Thanks.

> public static String DATA;

```
private void setData() {
        DATA = "";
        final String URI = ""http://megapolitan.kompas.com/read/2013/01/02/10533531/BMW.Rasyid.Rajasa.Diselimuti.Plastik.Abuabu"";
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DATA = new LoadNews().execute(URI).get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }.start();
}

private class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private String itemContent;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements element = doc.select("div.isi_berita2011 pt_5");
            itemContent = element.toString();
            return itemContent;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know why you're using Thread beside AsyncTask is executed on different thread itself .

Answer (score 0):

Put your DATA in a cache.  Use your URI as the key.
Take a look at [Android Objects Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841470/android-objects-cache)

Memory cache : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Disk cache : https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Comment: Hi Akos thanks for reply, but i hope your link, it is just image cache, if image i can,,

Comment: you can put any object in the cache,  it does not need to be an image.