# Is there a way to speed up Steam API update?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm using Steam Web API and need to check if the achievement list for a certain user and game is updated (when user gets an achievement). I am using `api.ISteamUserStats.GetUserStatsForGame`.

The problem is that, even though I am querying repeatedly, the list only updates to the new data after a delay of about one minute, thus rendering my app useless.

Any ideas on how to reduce this delay or maybe suggestions for a different approach?

Comment: I guess the only one who can speed that up is Steam itself.

Comment: I think @KlausD. is right. There is no way of speeding it up at your side..

Comment: As I unfortunately expected... Thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your question was kind of answered in the comments, here you have some more information:

It is nearly impossible to speed up an REST API call to -not under your control- servers like in this case. You can find some advice [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195105/7454177).

This answer applied to the **Steam API**:

1. Make **as few calls as possible** (like in the post). There are simple ways to stack requests in the Steam API like request much information at once (i.e. use `ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=SteamAPIKey&steamids=YourSteamIDs` to gather information for multiple users at once and use this data instead of a new query)
2. Keep calls as **simple as they can be**. (i.e. if you just need one fact -check for one game for example- build a query for just that and don´t ask for all games and check then...)
3. Think about **caching the data** - at least for certain users or data wich can be "recycled" and updated every few days/ months. (Again inspired by the other thread)
4. **Don´t call everything at once** (if it is possible). It *can* be faster to load segments or just the information you want to show -for now. If you call every query at the beginning of your script, this could be slower. **BUT**: keep in mind #1 and that it is more efficient to make one large query instead of multiple smaller. This one depends completly on the query. It is more efficient to load a friend list in one query but it is more efficient to load the important data first and the less important data afterwards.

Furthermore -obviously- check if you got enough processing power, some ram and a good connection. *Just for example: I let a hosted server make the querys and pass results to me later on.*