# How to cache objects into internal memory

Tags: android

I have one problem. I am creating some kind of heavy object every time when I open an activity. While using the program, this activity can be opened a lot of times, so every time I should wait while some heavy stuff is done. Is there any way to cache this large object into memory and get it from memory while activity is started for the second time. 
Or there is another way to do this ?

Comment: You could use a singleton.

Comment: You better use some service or background work not to slow the ui

Comment: Maybe using something like `LruCache`?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841470/android-objects-cache

Answer (score 1):

Save object as file:

```
FileOutputStream output = context.openFileOutput("object.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
outputStream.writeObject(objectToSave);
outputStream.close();
```

Load object from file

```
FileInputStream input = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(input);
Object obj = inputStream.readObject();
inputStream.close();
ObjectToSave ots;
if(obj instanceof ObjectToSave)
{
its = (ObjectToSave) obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend Application](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/) and store/retrieve arbitrary object(s) from anywhere, anytime.

So your activity will look like this

```
void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   GlobalState state = (GlobalState) getApplicationContext();
   MyObject obj = state.getMyObject();
   if (obj == null) {
      obj = createHeavyObject();
      state.setMyObject(obj);
   }
   // your business logic here
}
```