# Example of JakeWhartons DiskLruCache

Tags: android, caching

I want to use the `DiskLruCache` from Jake Wharton in my Android app based on API Level 7+. I would use it in my ListView to Cache downloaded images on SdCard but i didn't understood the usage of this library.
Can anybody show me a example of how to get Bitmaps from this Cache or put Bitmaps in the cache? ( key = filePath, value = Bitmap )

I found no method to get the Value of this Snapshot Object.

Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used getBitmap() in the sample someone posted here.

This is the answer you're looking for under a different title. You will have to create a Utils for some of the code but it's pretty straightforward.

Good Luck!

[Using DiskLruCache in android 4.0 does not provide for openCache method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185898/using-disklrucache-in-android-4-0-does-not-provide-for-opencache-method)

Comment: I'm using: imgCache = new DiskLruImageCache(context, "images", DISK_CACHE_SIZE); imgCache.put(id, scaleImage(bmp)); to store. And Bitmap b = imgCache.getBitmap(id); to retrieve a bitmap from this cache. But it says image not found. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have the same issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this very easy to use DiskLruCache wrapper: https://github.com/fhucho/simple-disk-cache

Comment: Many unnecessary step?

Comment: I know it's quite an old post but in case you remember. Have you checked whether Jake Wharton's library maintains in-memory cache out-of-the-box?

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't.