# Android Disk LRU Cache reset when app is closed

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

Is this really the intended behavior? I can't found any documentation on this issue.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054007/how-check-if-a-disklrucache-already-exists-android?rq=1

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it. Cheers

Comment: what are you doing in onStop, onDestroy?

Comment: Is there anything I should do? Currently I'm doing nothing on onStop and onDestroy