# How can I generate a key for a cache that stores bitmaps?

Tags: android, image, caching, bitmap

I would like to integrate this caching mechanism in my app: [Using DiskLruCache in android 4.0 does not provide for openCache method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185898/using-disklrucache-in-android-4-0-does-not-provide-for-opencache-method)

Now, when I have the bitmap, which key shall I use? Or better: How can I generate a key?

It would be good if I could generate the key from the bitmap itself so that I can later call `contains(String key)` to check whether the bitmap is already in the cache.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate the key by hashing the Bitmap bytes, ensuring to a high probability that no two Bitmaps will result in the same key, unless they are identical.

You will need to convert your Bitmap into a byte array to use the built-in [MessageDigest](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html) library.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(); // load your bitmap...
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");  
digest.update(byteArray);
byte[] keyBytes = digest.digest(byteArray);
```

Afterwards, convert the key bytes into a string with [a Bytes to Hex function like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java).